# python: how shall I extract one column and delete this column for a matrix array?

Tags: arrays, matrix

for example

```
xx=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

now I want to extract the first one column for xx; and delete this column then xx becomes to be

```
[[2, 3], [5, 6], [7, 8], [11, 12]];
```

how shall I?

Comment: Please mention the language in which you are attempting to do this. I could guess python or js. But there are many more possibilities.

Comment: thanks for your advice; it is python;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution I can think of -

`xx = list(map(lambda x: x[1:], xx))`